# to_json with conditional :except in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a User model with an id, name and url attribute and an associated Preferences model with an id and show_my_url fields.

I want to render my user as json but only include the url attribute if user.preferences.show_my_url is 'true'.

How can i remove the users url attribute based on the preferences so that it´s not included in the to_json rendering.

Comment: the simplest way is to overload `to_json` method if you don't need a default one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def to_json(opts={})
  except = [] # Standard except, may contain some stuff you want to exclude
  except << :url unless self.preferences.show_my_url
  super(opts.merge(:except => except))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is Serializers:  [JSON Serializers in ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).  This is the proper way to do it.

So to for your problem, you could implement something like this on your user class:

```
def as_json
  preferences.try(:show_my_url) ? to_json : to_json(:except => :url)
end
```